# Does the system have a periodic orbit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system
$$
x'=y(1-x)=f(x,y)
$$
$$
y'=x(1-y)=g(x,y)
$$
Does it have a periodic orbit?

I consider several methods:

I first try to apply Dulac's criteria:
$$
div(\mathbb{f})=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-x-y
$$
I cannot say if this one change the sign...

Also, if I consider the function $V(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2$ and compute
$$
\dot V(x,y)=xx'+yy'=xy(2-x-y)
$$

I still cannot find the annulus so that it change the sign...

Comment: Note that $(x-y)'=-(x-y)$

Comment: Any periodic orbit in the plane must go around a critical point, but both critical points lie along the line $y = x$, which is invariant.

Comment: @whpowell96 What is name of the result that you use here? Can we apply Dulac?

Comment: @Cesareo Can you please explain it? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if the result I state has a name but it uses index theory and it can be found in Guckenheimer and Holmes. Cesareo's proof is probably a bit easier, as it can be used to show that the line $y=x$ is a globally attracting invariant set.

Comment: @whpowell96 Your "critical points" mean the equilibrium points? That is $x'=y'=0$. So it seems that only two equilibrium pints $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: @whpowell96 So why $y=x$ is a globally attracting invariant set? So you mean these two points are asymptotic stable?

Comment: No, close to $(0,0)$ the system is approximately $x'=y$, $y'=x$, which is repulsing along the diagonal. The system is also separable, in that $\frac{xx'}{1-x}=xy=\frac{yy'}{1-y}$. Integrating this gives the level sets along which solutions move.

Comment: I advise you to use the public domain simulator [here](https://aeb019.hosted.uark.edu/pplane.html) (just type $y*(1-x)$ and $x*(1-y)$ in the two boxes then click on the "Graph Phase Plane" button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in Cesareo's comment, $(x-y)' = -(x-y)$, which implies that the quantity $x-y$ is exponentially decreasing and the points in the $\omega$-limit set of any point must have $x-y=0$, which means that they lie on the line $y=x$. However, there can be no periodic orbits on a line for an autonomous system other than a trivial fixed point. The existence of a nontrivial periodic orbit on the line would imply the orbit must pass through the same points on the line, but traveling in a different direction, which is impossible due to uniqueness. This can also be seen by explicitly solving the system along the line, which is the logistic equation.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain how to solve the system? Do you mean change variable let $u=x-y$?

Comment: If $x=y$, then we have $x' = x(1-x)$ and the same equation for $y$. This is a seperable first-order equation.